# ftplib.error_perm: 500 not understood downloading file from ftp

Tags: python

I am newbie to python and  trying to download all csv  files from a ftp folder   but I receive this error.
 this is my code:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.128.0.20', 'bingo', 'Password')
ftp.cwd('/')
filematch = '*.csv'


for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    fhandle = open(filename,'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR' + filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()
```

this is my error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./dirmon.py", line 65, in <module>
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR' + filename, fhandle.write)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 406, in retrbinary
        conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 368, in transfercmd
        return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 331, in ntransfercmd
        resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
        return self.getresp()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
        raise error_perm, resp
    ftplib.error_perm: 500 RETRRINGGODATA-2014-07-02.CSV not understood
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

missing space at `ftp.retrbinary`: (I also prfer `with` statement):

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.128.0.20', 'bingo', 'Password')
ftp.cwd('/')
filematch = '*.csv'
target_dir = '/home/toor/ringolist'
import os

for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(target_file_name ,'wb') as fhandle:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, fhandle.write)
```

Comment: it can not be the same :)

Comment: do You have permissions to create file ? add between `for` and `with` statements: `print('filename: %s' % filename)`

Comment: I have 50 odd files  it prints  most the filenames and still same error on ftplib.error_perm: 500 RETRRINGGODATA-2014-05-23.CSV not understood  when I looked in the file its everything the same

Comment: pls change `ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)` to `ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, fhandle.write)` and show result (remember to add space between `RETR` and `%s`)

Comment: Thanks WBAR it solved it can you tell me where does these files normally saved in local as i have not givenany destination.

Comment: You can also use `with ftplib.FTP(...) as ftp:`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
```

And try to change:

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, fhandle.write)
```

to:

```
ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {filename}", fhandle.write)
```

It works for me.

Source: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/download-and-upload-files-in-ftp-server-using-python

Comment: This answer works on Python 3 only, but might be preferable at this time.